# root element using jersey

Tags: java, json, eclipse, jersey

i must get an ArrayList in json format, what i'm missing is the root element, infact i get this json:

```
[{"age":27,"firstName":"Lorenzo","id":1,"lastName":"Volponi"},{"age":60,"firstName":"Alberto","id":2,"lastName":"Volponi"}...
```

i think i must get something like

```
["contatti": {"age":27,"firstName":"Lorenzo","id":1,"lastName":"Volponi"},{"age":60,"firstName":"Alberto","id":2,"lastName":"Volponi"}...
```

i'm using jersey on eclipse, here's my web service:

```
@Path("/jsonServices")
public class JerseyRestService {
public ArrayList<Student> Rubrica=new ArrayList<Student>();
    @GET
    @Path("/print/{name}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ArrayList<Student> produceJSON( @PathParam("name") String name ) {
        setRubrica();

        ArrayList<Student> Risultati=new ArrayList<Student>();
        int cc=1;
        for(int i=0; i< Rubrica.size();i++){
            String nome=Rubrica.get(i).getFirstName();
            String cognome=Rubrica.get(i).getLastName();
            if(Rubrica.get(i).getFirstName().equals(name)|| Rubrica.get(i).getLastName().equals(name))
            {
                Risultati.add(Rubrica.get(i));
            }
        }   
        return Risultati;
    }
    @GET
    @Path("/print")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ArrayList<Student> rubica() {
        setRubrica();
        return Rubrica;

    }
public void setRubrica(){
    Rubrica.add(new Student("Lorenzo","Volponi",27,1,"0712811157"));
    Rubrica.add(new Student("Alberto","Volponi",60,2,"0712811157")); ...

}
}
```

thank you

Comment: The second snippet you proposed is not valid JSON.

Comment: mmm what is supposed to be?

Comment: The first one is correct. You're returning an `ArrayList` which maps to a JSON array.

Comment: the fact is that i'm using codenameone and the method to parse the json is this:

JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
                  Map h = p.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
                
                  ArrayList<Map<String, String>> myList = (ArrayList<Map<String,String>>)h.get("DocumentType");

so it require a "DocumentType"

Comment: Either change that code to parse the JSON as an array or change your jersey code to return a POJO which has a member called `DocumentType`.

Comment: i'm sorry i'm so noob but i work with web service and codenameone just about two days...how can i parse the json as an array ? if is it possibile i don't want to use POJO or install other plugin...my working machine is just compromized as it is, thank you

Comment: Can you use a different parser? One that handles POJOs?

Comment: i've solved as @SotiriosDelimanolis said parsing the json as an array